# How to avoid multiple AspectJ weavers running when using aop.xml in and out of war file

Tags: aspectj, spring-aop

I have a war file which contains a number of AspectJ aspects and an aop.xml file which specifies the packages these aspects apply to. I enable aop load time weaving through Spring by adding this line to my Spring config:

```
<context:load-time-weaver/>
```

This starts up the default weaver which for my app server is: org.springframework.instrument.classloading.weblogic.WebLogicLoadTimeWeaver.

The problem is, we also have another aspect & associated aop.xml file define on the system classpath which is triggered by a -javaagent:lib/aspectjweaver-1.7.4.jar and hence loads up another weaver.

The 2 weavers seem to clash as I see:

```
[ChangeAwareClassLoader@70b2974f] warning define generated class failed -- (LinkageError) loader (instance of  weblogic/utils/classloaders/ChangeAwareClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "x/y/MyClassImpl$AjcClosure1"
loader (instance of  weblogic/utils/classloaders/ChangeAwareClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "x/y/MyClassImpl$AjcClosure1"
java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of  weblogic/utils/classloaders/ChangeAwareClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "x/y/MyClassImpl$AjcClosure1"
```

I wondered if there was a way to make the war use the aspectjweaver defined by the javaagent line so I only have 1 weaver running? Note I don't want to move my aspects from the war to the system classpath as they have a number of dependencies on other libraries.

Any guidance much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you can use one of the special properties to configure AspectJ LTW to turn off the agent related weaver so that it doesn't get created and the alternate is used instead. Basically set this system property at launch time:

```
-Daj.weaving.loadersToSkip=org.springframework.instrument.classloading.weblogic.WebLogicLoadTimeWeaver
```

Comment: Many thanks for your fast response but this doesn't seem to make any difference. I am going to try & comment out the <context:load-time-weaver/> line & see if this helps..